# Не работают некоторые else if

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Друзья, привет, подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть else if, где идет проверка введенного параметра на "Цвет волос" и "Цвет кожи", и когда я ввожу одно из этих значений, условный оператор else if не выполняется? Причём всё остальное работает на ура. Вот код:

```
    #include <iostream>

class Human 
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    std::string colorofhair;
    std::string colorofskin;
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
};

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    Human firstHuman;

    firstHuman.name = "Андрей";
    firstHuman.age = 21;
    firstHuman.sex = "Мужчина";
    firstHuman.colorofhair = "Чёрный";
    firstHuman.colorofskin = "Белый";
    firstHuman.weight = 67;
    firstHuman.height = 185;

    while (true)
    {
        std::string value;
        std::cout << "Введите свойство, которое вы хотите узнать?: ";
        std::cin >> value;

        if (value == "Имя")
        {
            std::cout << "Имя человека: " << firstHuman.name << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Возраст")
        {
            std::cout << "Возраст человека: " << firstHuman.age << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Пол")
        {
            std::cout << "Пол человека: " << firstHuman.sex << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Цвет волос") // Не работает
        {
            std::cout << "Цвет волос человека: " << firstHuman.colorofhair << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Цвет кожи") // Не работает
        {
            std::cout << "Цвет кожи человека: " << firstHuman.colorofhair << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Вес")
        {
            std::cout << "Вес человека: " << firstHuman.weight << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Рост")
        {
            std::cout << "Рост человека: " << firstHuman.height << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "К сожалению такого свойства у этого человека нет." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `>>` считывает до пробела, замените на `getline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях уже написали, но я распишу чуть подробнее: 
`cin` считывает до пробела, потому и были проблемы именно в тех местах, где строка состоит из двух слов. Чтобы это исправить, нужно использовать функцию `getline`, которая считает значение полностью, вот так это будет выглядеть:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Библиотека, которую необходимо подключить для getline
class Human 
{
  public:
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    std::string colorofhair;
    std::string colorofskin;
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
};

int main()
{
  system("chcp 1251 > nul");
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

  Human firstHuman;

  firstHuman.name = "Андрей";
  firstHuman.age = 21;
  firstHuman.sex = "Мужчина";
  firstHuman.colorofhair = "Чёрный";
  firstHuman.colorofskin = "Белый";
  firstHuman.weight = 67;
  firstHuman.height = 185;

  while (true)
  {
      std::string value;
      std::cout << "Введите свойство, которое вы хотите узнать?: ";
      getline(std::cin, value);  // вот такой синтаксис

      if (value == "Имя")
      {
          std::cout << "Имя человека: " << firstHuman.name << std::endl;
      }
      else if (value == "Возраст")
      {
          std::cout << "Возраст человека: " << firstHuman.age << std::endl;
      }
      else if (value == "Пол")
      {
          std::cout << "Пол человека: " << firstHuman.sex << std::endl;
      }
      else if (value == "Цвет волос") // Не работает
      {
          std::cout << "Цвет волос человека: " << firstHuman.colorofhair << std::endl;
      }
      else if (value == "Цвет кожи") // Не работает
      {
          std::cout << "Цвет кожи человека: " << firstHuman.colorofskin << std::endl;
      }
      else if (value == "Вес")
      {
          std::cout << "Вес человека: " << firstHuman.weight << std::endl;
      }
      else if (value == "Рост")
      {
          std::cout << "Рост человека: " << firstHuman.height << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "К сожалению такого свойства у этого человека нет." << std::endl;
      }
  }
}
```

P.S. вы и в цвете волос, и в цвете кожи выводили цвет волос

Comment: Да Спасибо)

Comment: Не работает getline, пробовал и std::getline, что я делаю не так? Visual Studio подсвечивает красным :/